# Magento2.2 - Error in catalog search

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, search, catalogsearch

I have facing problem on search product(s) from my website.

Someone please help me out to know what happens in this error.

When I search for a product in the site search, for example "Dress", the magento does not return the registered dresses, but this screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxSBZ.jpg

Showing the category "Female" which is where "Dress" is, but it does not return products.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Comment: open view source of that page, that page is broken. Or check log files.

Comment: does not have error information on the page or logs

Comment: can you share URL?

Comment: https://shoppingcity.com.br yeap @kunj

Comment: I hid the catalog by the hour here on the right side https://imgur.com/a/NimPopo @kunj

Comment: you have issue with price filter.

Comment: when you see this ?

Comment: you can see HTML not render after `Preço` and that for filter section.

Comment: Do you know how I can solve this? @kunj

Comment: Please remove left side filter from search page. Or you need to debug it by set magento to developer mode.

Comment: I removed the price filter on the left side and still the problem continues

Comment: check it on private window it is working for me

Comment: OMG DUDe worked. Thanks a lot for the help. What can I do to get you started again?

Comment: you need to debug it, happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug price filter or can disable it for testing. Also can enable developer mode to see exception errors.